# Set an existing column to tooltip in google visualization api?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is it possible to set an existing column to be used as a html tooltip for a bar chart in google api without having to perform the following:

```
data.addColumn({type:'string',role:'tooltip'});
```

then adding the tooltip specific fields after converting the data to a datatable? Is there something like a:

```
data.setColumn(2, {type:'string',role:'tooltip'})
```

such that I dont have to adda new one? Does such a function exist?

My data is currently like this:

```
[
["Name", "Number", "Tooltip"],
["James", 1, "Tooltip for James"],
["Kyle", 2, "Tooltip for Kyle"]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the DataTable#setColumnProperty method to set the role:

```
data.setColumnProperty(2, 'role', 'tooltip');
```